# Inconsitent general solutions of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

General solutions of trigonometric equations are given by:

> If $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$, then $x = n \pi + (-1)^ny$
>   If $\cos(x) = \cos(y)$, then $x = 2n \pi \pm  y$

If we consider an example,

$$
 \sin(x) = \sin(30^\circ)  \\
 \implies x = n \pi + (-1)^n30^\circ \\
 [where \pi=180^\circ]
$$ 
which can be worked out for the values of n from -1 to 10, which are

$$\begin{array}{cc}
n&x (\text{degrees})\\
-1&-210\\
0&30\\
1&150\\
2&390\\
3&510\\
4&750\\
5&870\\
6&1110\\
7&1230\\
8&1470\\
9&1590\\
10&1830\\
\end{array}
$$

Now $$
\sin(x)=\sin(30^\circ)=\cos(60^\circ) \\
\implies \sqrt{1-\cos^2x} = cos(60^\circ) \\
\implies 1-\cos^2x = (\frac{1}{2})^2 \\
\implies \cos^2x = 1 - (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{3}{4} \\
\implies \cos(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos(30^\circ)
$$

So for $\cos(x) = \cos(30^\circ)$, we have
$$x = 2n\pi \pm 30^\circ$$

Solving for values yields

$$\begin{array}{cc}
n&x (\text{degrees})\\
-1&-390,330\\
0&-30,30\\
1&330,390\\
2&690,750\\
3&1050,1110\\
4&1410, 1470\\
5&1770, 1830\\
6&2130,2190\\
7&2490,2550\\
8&2850, 2910\\
9&3210,3270\\
10&3570,3630\\
\end{array}
$$

If you compare the two, you'll find that only some of the values exist in both solutions, and they both have values that don't exist in the other value set.

**I was expecting both of these to be exactly equal. What is the cause of this inconsistency?**

One "practical" answer that I was able to come up with is :

If you're provided with the information that $\sin(x) = \sin(30^\circ)$, AND $\cos(x) = \cos(30^\circ)$, then both those conditions would invalidate the extra results in both value sets (since those values will satisfy only one equation),

Which leads me to the conclusion that both statements $\sin(x) = \sin(30^\circ)$ and $\cos(x) = \cos(30^\circ)$ are not equivalent.
But does that mean there's a fault in the conversion of equation from sin terms to cos terms?

If so, how could I start with $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$, correctly convert these to cosine terms and proceed to get the the same results as I would with sin terms?

Comment: It is because you take square root of $cos^2(x)$, assuming $cos(x)$ is positive.

Comment: Angles should be in *radians*: nπ+30° is inconsistent.

Comment: @Bernard fixed that technicality

Comment: @corbah You are correct. Upon considering the negative values, they give the solutions for x that positive values didn't, e.g. $x = 210^\circ$. However, all the extra values, they'll just simply have to be rejected because they didn't fit the original equation of sin x = sin 30deg, correct?

Comment: @Bernard - Actually, it's no more inconsistent than writing 3ft + 4 in is inconsistent.

Comment: It is, because in your example, both numbers have units with them.

Answer (score 1):

Its best in situations like this to think in terms of the unit circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x=\sin y,x=n\pi+(-1)^ny$ where $n$ is any integer

For even $n=2m$(say) $x=2m\pi+y\ \ \ \ (1)$

For odd $n=2m+1$(say) $x=(2m+1)\pi-y$

Now let $X=\dfrac\pi2-x, Y=\dfrac\pi2-y\implies\cos x=\cos y$

$(1)\implies\dfrac\pi2-X=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2-Y\iff X=-2m\pi+Y$

$(2)\implies\dfrac\pi2-X=(2m+1)\pi-\left(\dfrac\pi2-Y\right)\iff X=-2m\pi-Y$

which is same as $$\cos X=\cos Y\implies X=2r\pi\pm Y$$ where $r$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

A) If $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$, then $x = n \pi + (-1)^ny$
 B) If $\cos(x) = \cos(y)$, then $x = 2n \pi \pm  y$

A) and B) are given *different independent*  problems and so they *need not* be consistent.